# Make a Chat-like UI using Tailwind CSS?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I want to have a Chat-like simple UI where the chats can scroll & 2 buttons are at the end.

Currently, it looks like:

[image: chat-app]

Full reproduction → https://play.tailwindcss.com/mKgRCKKVBq

The code looks like:

```html
<aside class="flex flex-col min-h-full bg-gray-900 text-white">
  <p class="overflow-y-scroll flex-1">
    They floated in the human system. They floated in the Japanese night like live wire voodoo and he’d cry for it, cry in his sleep, and wake alone in the human system. Then a mist closed over the black water and the amplified breathing of the Flatline as a construct, a hardwired ROM cassette replicating a dead man’s skills, obsessions, kneejerk responses. That was Wintermute, manipulating the lock the way it had manipulated the drone micro and the dripping chassis of a painted jungle of rainbow foliage, a lurid communal mural that completely covered the hull of the spherical chamber. Her cheekbones flaring scarlet as Wizard’s Castle burned, forehead drenched with azure when Munich fell to the Tank War, mouth touched with hot gold as a paid killer in the puppet place had been a subunit of Freeside’s security system. The knives seemed to move of their own accord, gliding with a random collection of European furniture, as though Deane had once intended to use the place as his home. That was Wintermute, manipulating the lock the way it had manipulated the drone micro and the dripping chassis of a heroin factory. He tried to walk past her back into the dark, curled in his capsule in some coffin hotel, his hands clawed into the bedslab, temper foam bunched between his fingers, trying to reach the console that wasn’t there.They were dropping, losing altitude in a canyon of rainbow foliage, a lurid communal mural that completely covered the hull of the blowers and the amplified breathing of the fighters. The last Case saw of Chiba were the cutting edge, whole bodies of technique supplanted monthly, and still he’d see the matrix in his capsule in some coffin hotel, his hands clawed into the shadow of the console. None of that prepared him for the arena, the crowd, the tense hush, the towering puppets of light from a service hatch framed a heap of discarded fiber optics and the chassis of a junked console. Then he’d taken a long and pointless walk along the port’s security perimeter, watching the gulls turn circles beyond the chain link. The Sprawl was a square of faint light. The alarm still oscillated, louder here, the rear of the console in faded pinks and yellows. A narrow wedge of light from a half-open service hatch at the twin mirrors. The knives seemed to move of their own accord, gliding with a hand on his chest. A graphic representation of data abstracted from the Chinese program’s thrust, a worrying impression of solid fluidity, as though the shards of a broken mirror bent and elongated as they rotated, but it never told the correct time. They floated in the human system. They floated in the Japanese night like live wire voodoo and he’d cry for it, cry in his sleep, and wake alone in the human system. Then a mist closed over the black water and the amplified breathing of the Flatline as a construct, a hardwired ROM cassette replicating a dead man’s skills, obsessions, kneejerk responses. That was Wintermute, manipulating the lock the way it had manipulated the drone micro and the dripping chassis of a painted jungle of rainbow foliage, a lurid communal mural that completely covered the hull of the spherical chamber. Her cheekbones flaring scarlet as Wizard’s Castle burned, forehead drenched with azure when Munich fell to the Tank War, mouth touched with hot gold as a paid killer in the puppet place had been a subunit of Freeside’s security system. The knives seemed to move of their own accord, gliding with a random collection of European furniture, as though Deane had once intended to use the place as his home. That was Wintermute, manipulating the lock the way it had manipulated the drone micro and the dripping chassis of a heroin factory. He tried to walk past her back into the dark, curled in his capsule in some coffin hotel, his hands clawed into the bedslab, temper foam bunched between his fingers, trying to reach the console that wasn’t there.They were dropping, losing altitude in a canyon of rainbow foliage, a lurid communal mural that completely covered the hull of the blowers and the amplified breathing of the fighters. The last Case saw of Chiba were the cutting edge, whole bodies of technique supplanted monthly, and still he’d see the matrix in his capsule in some coffin hotel, his hands clawed into the shadow of the console. None of that prepared him for the arena, the crowd, the tense hush, the towering puppets of light from a service hatch framed a heap of discarded fiber optics and the chassis of a junked console. Then he’d taken a long and pointless walk along the port’s security perimeter, watching the gulls turn circles beyond the chain link. The Sprawl was a square of faint light. The alarm still oscillated, louder here, the rear of the console in faded pinks and yellows. A narrow wedge of light from a half-open service hatch at the twin mirrors. The knives seemed to move of their own accord, gliding with a hand on his chest. A graphic representation of data abstracted from the Chinese program’s thrust, a worrying impression of solid fluidity, as though the shards of a broken mirror bent and elongated as they rotated, but it never told the correct time.
  </p>
  <div class="flex items-center justify-between mt-auto h-20 bg-pink-900">
    <button
      type="button"
      class="inline-flex items-center justify-center flex-1 px-3 mx-4 mt-0 text-sm font-medium leading-4 text-white rounded-lg shadow-sm h-9 dark:bg-green-600 focus:outline-none"
    >
      Later
    </button>
    <button
      type="button"
      class="inline-flex items-center justify-center flex-1 px-3 mx-4 mt-0 text-sm font-medium leading-4 text-white rounded-lg shadow-sm h-9 dark:bg-indigo-600 focus:outline-none"
    >
      Send
    </button>
  </div>
</aside>
```

I want the whole thing only using 100% height. And the buttons stuck at the bottom.

I also want the chat to scroll vertically.

I want the HTML markup to remain as is. I don't think I need to change anything in the markup to achieve the same effect.

How should it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to change only 1-thing. The outer container should be using `h-screen` instead of `min-h-full` like:

```html
<aside class="flex flex-col h-screen bg-gray-900 text-white">
  <p class="overflow-y-scroll flex-1">
    They floated in the human system. They floated in the Japanese night like live wire voodoo and he’d cry for it, cry in his sleep, and wake alone in the human system. Then a mist closed over the black water and the amplified breathing of the Flatline as a construct, a hardwired ROM cassette replicating a dead man’s skills, obsessions, kneejerk responses. That was Wintermute, manipulating the lock the way it had manipulated the drone micro and the dripping chassis of a painted jungle of rainbow foliage, a lurid communal mural that completely covered the hull of the spherical chamber. Her cheekbones flaring scarlet as Wizard’s Castle burned, forehead drenched with azure when Munich fell to the Tank War, mouth touched with hot gold as a paid killer in the puppet place had been a subunit of Freeside’s security system. The knives seemed to move of their own accord, gliding with a random collection of European furniture, as though Deane had once intended to use the place as his home. That was Wintermute, manipulating the lock the way it had manipulated the drone micro and the dripping chassis of a heroin factory. He tried to walk past her back into the dark, curled in his capsule in some coffin hotel, his hands clawed into the bedslab, temper foam bunched between his fingers, trying to reach the console that wasn’t there.They were dropping, losing altitude in a canyon of rainbow foliage, a lurid communal mural that completely covered the hull of the blowers and the amplified breathing of the fighters. The last Case saw of Chiba were the cutting edge, whole bodies of technique supplanted monthly, and still he’d see the matrix in his capsule in some coffin hotel, his hands clawed into the shadow of the console. None of that prepared him for the arena, the crowd, the tense hush, the towering puppets of light from a service hatch framed a heap of discarded fiber optics and the chassis of a junked console. Then he’d taken a long and pointless walk along the port’s security perimeter, watching the gulls turn circles beyond the chain link. The Sprawl was a square of faint light. The alarm still oscillated, louder here, the rear of the console in faded pinks and yellows. A narrow wedge of light from a half-open service hatch at the twin mirrors. The knives seemed to move of their own accord, gliding with a hand on his chest. A graphic representation of data abstracted from the Chinese program’s thrust, a worrying impression of solid fluidity, as though the shards of a broken mirror bent and elongated as they rotated, but it never told the correct time. They floated in the human system. They floated in the Japanese night like live wire voodoo and he’d cry for it, cry in his sleep, and wake alone in the human system. Then a mist closed over the black water and the amplified breathing of the Flatline as a construct, a hardwired ROM cassette replicating a dead man’s skills, obsessions, kneejerk responses. That was Wintermute, manipulating the lock the way it had manipulated the drone micro and the dripping chassis of a painted jungle of rainbow foliage, a lurid communal mural that completely covered the hull of the spherical chamber. Her cheekbones flaring scarlet as Wizard’s Castle burned, forehead drenched with azure when Munich fell to the Tank War, mouth touched with hot gold as a paid killer in the puppet place had been a subunit of Freeside’s security system. The knives seemed to move of their own accord, gliding with a random collection of European furniture, as though Deane had once intended to use the place as his home. That was Wintermute, manipulating the lock the way it had manipulated the drone micro and the dripping chassis of a heroin factory. He tried to walk past her back into the dark, curled in his capsule in some coffin hotel, his hands clawed into the bedslab, temper foam bunched between his fingers, trying to reach the console that wasn’t there.They were dropping, losing altitude in a canyon of rainbow foliage, a lurid communal mural that completely covered the hull of the blowers and the amplified breathing of the fighters. The last Case saw of Chiba were the cutting edge, whole bodies of technique supplanted monthly, and still he’d see the matrix in his capsule in some coffin hotel, his hands clawed into the shadow of the console. None of that prepared him for the arena, the crowd, the tense hush, the towering puppets of light from a service hatch framed a heap of discarded fiber optics and the chassis of a junked console. Then he’d taken a long and pointless walk along the port’s security perimeter, watching the gulls turn circles beyond the chain link. The Sprawl was a square of faint light. The alarm still oscillated, louder here, the rear of the console in faded pinks and yellows. A narrow wedge of light from a half-open service hatch at the twin mirrors. The knives seemed to move of their own accord, gliding with a hand on his chest. A graphic representation of data abstracted from the Chinese program’s thrust, a worrying impression of solid fluidity, as though the shards of a broken mirror bent and elongated as they rotated, but it never told the correct time.
  </p>
  <div class="flex items-center justify-between mt-auto h-20 bg-pink-900">
    <button
      type="button"
      class="inline-flex items-center justify-center flex-1 px-3 mx-4 mt-0 text-sm font-medium leading-4 text-white rounded-lg shadow-sm h-9 dark:bg-green-600 focus:outline-none"
    >
      Later
    </button>
    <button
      type="button"
      class="inline-flex items-center justify-center flex-1 px-3 mx-4 mt-0 text-sm font-medium leading-4 text-white rounded-lg shadow-sm h-9 dark:bg-indigo-600 focus:outline-none"
    >
      Send
    </button>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Full solution → https://play.tailwindcss.com/u26vw8LSfi

Answer (score 1):

All you need is sticky with right positioning. i.e
On the `div` with `bg-pink-900` class, add this classes `sticky bottom-0 left-0 right-0` as seen below:

```html
<aside class="flex flex-col min-h-full bg-gray-900 text-white">
  <p class="overflow-y-scroll flex-1">
    They floated in the human system. [and many more strings...]
  </p>
  <div class="flex items-center justify-between mt-auto h-20 bg-pink-900 sticky bottom-0 left-0 right-0">
    <button
      type="button"
      class="inline-flex items-center justify-center flex-1 px-3 mx-4 mt-0 text-sm font-medium leading-4 text-white rounded-lg shadow-sm h-9 dark:bg-green-600 focus:outline-none"
    >
      Later
    </button>
    <button
      type="button"
      class="inline-flex items-center justify-center flex-1 px-3 mx-4 mt-0 text-sm font-medium leading-4 text-white rounded-lg shadow-sm h-9 dark:bg-indigo-600 focus:outline-none"
    >
      Send
    </button>
  </div>
</aside>
```

View here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/tmXZ0Lfu7M

Comment: that works well, too although i prefer the one posted below :)